# Java - parsing logic

Tags: java, parsing

```
SAMPLE DATA

ABC                  MP    XP
2RMM2,NS-0            0     0
5RMM2,NS-0            0     0
12RMM2,NS-0           0     0
RXT-1                       7
END
```

This is sample log file content. I want to fetch MP,XP parameter values for all values under ABC Column.Sometimes the value of MP/XP may not be present.But I want to replace it with a default value if not.
Tried to use StringTokenizer as well as split method, but as in RXT-1 line, unable to identify if the value is for MP or XP
How to parse this file thereby keeping correct parameter value for MP/XP for each line?

Comment: Add the code that fails you in the RXT-1 line to the post. You would have to tokenize based on the delimiter the log file is using. Is it spaces or tabs?

Comment: Simple: by writing a program that reads the file correctly. Anyway, what kind of file is that supposed to be? Is it just a text file? Or some kid of spreadsheet document?

Comment: @XaverKapeller This is a text file

Comment: @Ma3x These are spaces. I tried this strLine_log.replaceAll("( )+", " "); to replace all spaces by single and then tokenize.. but as in RXT-1 line, unable to track if MP/XP value

Comment: And where is this file coming from? Are you generating it? If yes the modify it to something that is properly computer readable and not so much human readable.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - Log file is being generated at remote server, I am simply pulling the file and applying parsing logic

Comment: Then the first thing you have to find out is if this text file has a defined structure. More specifically what is delimiting the columns. Is it tabs (if yes, how many?) or spaces (if yes, what is the max length of the first column - the header gives you that info). By parsing the header first you will know how many characters to expect max in each column. That's usually what headers are for.

Comment: Then what exactly are you having trouble with? When you parse the file you can tell using the position of the headers  to which column a value belongs. For example value 0 is at position 43 in line 6. In the header at position 44 is MP so this value must belong to the MP column.

Comment: @Rinky This is not how SO works. You should not come here, drop requirements; and then have discussions with people through comments to refine them. Instead: you give a clear example, you show your **existing** code and you point your specific question. We are not here to do your work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems fixed length records. With probably 6 positions for numbers.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("..."));
lines.stream()
    .skip(3)
    .forEach(line -> {
        //          10        20
        // 01234567890123456789012345678
        // ABC                  MP    XP
        // 12RMM2,NS-0           0     0
        String abc = line.replace("^(.*)\\s.*$", "$1");
        String mpS = line.substring(abc.length() + 1, 22).trim();
        String xpS = line.substring(22).trim();
        int mp = mpS.isEmpty() ? -1 : Integer.parseInt(mp);
        int xp = xpS.isEmpty() ? -1 : Integer.parseInt(xp);
        ...
    });
);
```